# dropzone js resetting preview after uploading

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am having trouble resetting the dropzone js preview upon successful upload.

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
    url: 'postupload.php',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 1,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: false,
    init: function() {
        dzClosure = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

        // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
        document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            dzClosure.processQueue();
        });

        //send all the form data along with the files:
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append("firstname", jQuery("#firstname").val());
            formData.append("lastname", jQuery("#lastname").val());

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, however I've been playing around with the code a little bit and I think I might have some kind of solution. It does not re-start the dropzone as I will like, but it does some trick to the user eye.

This is going to remove all the files or images from the preview, it has to be triggered by the submit button, it does not delete the images from server side.

```
$('div#animalImage')[0].dropzone.files.forEach(function (file) {
   file.previewElement.remove();
});
$('div#animalImage').removeClass('dz-started');
```

I hope it gives you some starting point. I am waiting for a better solution too.

Regards